# Save user selected color to localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been trying to save user selection to localstorage but the code is not working. I want it to save the color the user selects to localstorage so that if the user changes or refreshes the page the background color stays there.

```js
function change(list) {
    var val=list.options[list.selectedIndex].value;
    document.body.style.background=val;
}
$(function () {
    $('#changer').change(function () {
        localStorage.setItem('todoData', this.value);
});
if (localStorage.getItem('todoData')) {
    $('#changer')
      .val(localStorage.getItem('todoData'))
      .trigger('change');
    }
});
```

```css
#pageFooter{
    background-color: #F49080;
    color: white;
    text-align: right;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -50px;
    clear: both;
}
label{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
 <footer id="pageFooter">
    <label>Select Color</label>
    <select id="changer" onchange="change(this)">  
        <option value=""  selected disabled hidden> - - Select Color - -</option> 
        <option value="Black">Black</option>
        <option value="#D48166">Orange</option>
        <option value="DarkGreen">Dark Green</option>
        <option value="#D6A3FB">Pink</option>
        <option value="#003b49">Original</option>
    </select>
</footer>
```

Comment: Where is the code you have written to try and save/load the value?

Comment: its not working because there is no `localStorage`  code whatsoever ... use `localStorage.setItem()...`

Comment: You are not using localstorage at all in the code you posted? How have you tried solving your question and how has it not worked?

Comment: Please edit that into the question rather than posting it in the comments.

Comment: I have added the code

Answer (score 0):

I change it. The ordery would be. On page load you have to check if soem value is already setted in the localStorage. If yes it will set the color for the body.

Then if the change Event Listener fired it will change the color and store the value in the localStorage.

Without jQuery working example:

```
if( localStorage.getItem('todoData') ) {
  alert(localStorage.getItem('todoData'))
  document.body.style.background = localStorage.getItem('todoData');
}

function change(list)
{
  var val = list.options[list.selectedIndex].value;  
  document.body.style.background = val;
  localStorage.setItem('todoData', this.value);  
}
```

Comment: @DBS you are right! i will remove my answear

Comment: @MaikLowrey I tried the code, and when I refresh the page the color does not stay there

Comment: @Muhammad_786 but it have. you are remove the jquery part in your code? I updated my answear. i added a alert. if todoData in localStorage not setted the you will get  null.  if setted then you will get a alert().

Comment: Yes the alert is working, but I do not want to give alert, I want it to save the color, for example if I select Black and then refresh the page I want it to keep Black there. @MaikLowrey

Comment: @Muhammad_786 the code working. the alert was only to see for you that it working. because if you see the alert, you will know that a color was already setted in the localstorage. and if you change the select field he set the new color in localstorage and change it immidently in your dom.

Answer (score 0):

Update your code shown below:

```js
function change(list){
  var val=list.options[list.selectedIndex].value;
  document.body.style.background=val;                 
}
```

And change it to:

```js
function change(list) {
  var val=list.options[list.selectedIndex].value;
  var pageFooter = document.getElementById( "pageFooter");
  pageFooter .style.backgroundColor = val;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but that only changes color of the "pagefooter", I want it to save the background color which the user changes using localstorage.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).